# what is this css syntax?

Tags: css

what is this?I know it is css,but what is the syntax?

```
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    border:0;
    height:200px;
    width:750px;
}
```

Comment: This is... CSS syntax (as you correctly point out)? I'm not sure what else you expect us to say.

Comment: Read up [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: And [Selectors, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: I mean why there are so many names?holder,ul.sub,li.sub-li,a,img?

Comment: aha,I got that,thanks for your answers.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, it's just that the one coding this was too specific about what properties the `img` tag was going to have. That practice is discouraged in OOCSS ([Object-Oriented CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)), which is not a syntax in itself, but a way of working with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector uses the [Descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators), which is only whitespace characters between simple selecors.

For example `a img` specifies an `img` element that is a descendant of an `a` element, i.e. it's somewhere inside the element, but there can be any number of levels between them.

It would match the image in this code:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="car.gif" />
</a>
```

It would also match the image in this code:

```
<a href="#">
  <span>
    <span>
      <span>
        <img src="car.gif" />
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

As a comparison, using the [Child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) in `a > img`, would only match the image in the first example, not in the second example, as it specifies a direct descendant.

Comment: aha,I got that,thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

it means all the ul elements  which contain  `sub`  class which are in a div with id `holder`

all the li tags with class  which are in a div with id `holder`

and anchor tag and images existed  in a div with id `holder`

Comment: aha,I got that,thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a img {
```

This is specifying all images inside n hors inside li.sub-li inside ul.sub inside an element with I'd holder.

See here for more info 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Just a note: [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: -0.25 for linking to w3schools.  :P  There are far better resources out there.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with w3schools?

Comment: @SteveP: Take a look at the link in Sirko's comment.  Short version: w3schools is littered with outdated and outright wrong info.

Comment: aha,I got that,thanks for your answers.